# Is there any way to get live telemetry data from the DJI Mavic 2 Zoom to another unit, say a computer?

Tags: dji-sdk

As part of a course on my university we've been given the task of taking the live wind telemetry from a drone and then feeding it to a neural network so that it gives better estimates than just using a sensor.

The research we've concluded so far tells us that our drone, the DJI Mavic 2 Zoom, is only compatible with the Windows SDK but not the onboard SDK.

Simply our question is; is there any way for us to send the raw wind speed and direction data from the drones sensors to a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Create Android application with DJI Mobile SDK and send data from msdk to your computer with wifi.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK only provides the wind warning level(0, 1 and 2). It does not provide any information regarding the direction from which the wind is blowing or the actual speed of the wind.

The aircraft tries to stay in it's current position on it's own, even if there is moderate wind blowing. However the drone does not tell the user how much it has to work in which direction to negate the effect of the wind.

I assume you're better off with accessing real time wind information for your position from a weather service on the internet, if that's available in your country.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a wind meter app.
The best method is:

- Fly against the wind
- In virtualstick use angle mode, and set pitch and roll to 0   This will let the drone drift with the wind.
- Slowly rotate the yaw.
- Meassure the speed, when it stop increasing, the gps-speed gives you the windspeed and direction.

Warning, in strong wind you have to fly for quite a while against the wind.
The yaw rotation needs to be done due to the drone is never exactly leveled, and it will pick up speed at one direction. If turned,  it cancel that out.

Send the info to a server over internet/wifi.
I've done this on an android phone connected the controller.
Windows api doesn't seem to support virtualsticks, which I find strange. In that case it must be done on android or ios, and trasnmitted to a server. I might be wrong since I never used the windows api.